# How I can search specific keyword, Copy and export

Tags: vba, excel

I am not a expert user of excel. I want to know how I can search specific keyword, Copy and export all the rows into a new excel file or sheet. I found many posts about coping and exporting using excel but finally tired. I've attached a Photo. Please let me know the simplest, easiest and successful way. I don't know how and where to add the code in excel. I can do just +,- and x in excel.. I would be thankful to you.

Here you can see the Image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link will help you add the "Developer" option to your ribbon in Excel. This will allow you to add code in excel. You can right-click your sheet tab at the bottom of your spreadsheet (the one that says "top 1 million..." in your photo) and select "view code" to access a VBA editor.

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/create-a-macro.html

To search for a specific keyword you can use a for loop that cycles through all the cells in a coloumn using this code

```
' cell number and index are variables for row number
Dim cell_number As Integer
Dim index As Integer

For row_number = 1 To 20 

    For coloumn_number = 1 To 20 

        If Sheet1.Cells(cell_number, coloumn_number).Value = "enter keyword here" Then 

        'add code for whatever you want to do (like store data in an array for "export") 

        End If

    Next

Next
```

Comment: Hi Kevin thanks to help me. I followed all the steps but there is still an error and code couldn't be proceeded.here is the code that I was added please check                                                 cell number and index are variables for row number
Dim cell_number As Integer
Dim index As Integer

For row_number = 1 To 1000

    For coloumn_number = 1 To 3

        If Sheet1.Cells(cell_number, coloumn_number).Value = "forum" Then

        'add code for whatever you want to do (like store data in an array for "export")

        End If

    Next

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using macro's you can simply use a VLOOKUP formula and excel's filter feature. Here's how:

- Based on the numbering on your screenshot it looks like you don't
  have header row so first add a blank row at the top of the sheet.
  (Select the first row, right click on it, select insert)
- Now select the second cell in an empty column like C2 and insert this formula:   `=VLOOKUP("*forum*", $B1:$B$1000000,1, FALSE)`
- Copy over the formula to the rest of the cells in column C by selecting C2 and double clicking on the little black box in the bottom right corner of the cell
- You should now see a list of all the websites that have "forum" in it but with a lot of them repeating. So you'll need to filter the data by selecting cell C1 (should be empty), navigating to "Data" tab in the ribbon menu, and clicking the "Advanced" button in the "Sort & Filter" section.
- Click OK to the message box that says something like "Microsoft Excel cannot determine which row..."
- The "Advanced Filter" dialog should pop up. Check the "Unique records only" checkbox and leave all the other fields alone. Hit OK.
- Now you should have a list of all the addresses that you're looking for. Simply select column C and copy it over to a new workbook and do whatever you want to it.